# What is the fastest way to pause execution in c++

Tags: c++, performance, time

I would like to pause execution time in c++ and this is the code I got:

```
while (_run)
{
    //pause code
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(_interval_ns));

    //doing stuff
    _counter++;
    (*_mainSrcTick)(GetDeltaTime(), GetName());
    
    for (auto obj : _physicsList)
    {
        PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "PhysicsTick", "(d)", GetDeltaTime());
    }
    
    //used to mesure time
    LastTick = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
```

Just in case here is my delta time function which gets how many ths of my interval have past since my last tick:

```
double difference = std::chrono::duration<double,std::nano>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - LastTick).count();
double result = difference/_interval_ns  ;
return result;
```

The problem I have is that by not pausing apparently my code can run in a couple of us and with pausing for a little time even it takes milli seconds. So forth I want a way to pause that doesn't disrupt my program so much.

Before you wonder I do know how to use "using namespace" and this project runs on x64 (though I wouldn't mind if it could also be run on x86), links python with c++ and is multi threaded, though on the python side only. So I presume I need a faster way to pause or at least time so it can pause with a while loop. I don't want **ANY** 3rd party dependencies. I use VS 2019.

The purpose is to make do stuff happen at a fixed frequency of every _interval_ns. GetDeltaTime is so I can give any inaccuracies to dostuff but it would be better if the frequency is accurate not the delta time. I am looking for micro second accuracy and nano would be nice.

Comment: What is the value of `_interval_ns`?

Comment: Depends but usaully 1 000 000

Comment: Use https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait if your cpu supports it

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the time delay? The example code makes me suspect that you want some kind of `next_time = get_monotomic_counter() + my_delay; while(true) { do_stuff(); delay_until_monotomic_counter(next_time); next_time += my_delay; }` so that `do_stuff()` happens at a fixed frequency (e.g. 60 times per second) even when `do_stuff()` takes an unknown/variable amount of time.

Comment: Yes I need "do stuff" to happen at a fixed frequency and I want some way of controlling the frequency. This : `next_time = get_monotomic_counter() + my_delay; while(true) { do_stuff(); delay_until_monotomic_counter(next_time); next_time += my_delay; }` would be great to implement some how but `thread::sleep_until` is too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask your thread to sleep, it is unscheduled by the operating system, and rescheduling it takes some time.  If you want to pause for a very small amount of time, use `_mm_pause()`.  You may want to do it a fixed number of times based on your own measurements of how long it takes on your system.  Intel says it takes 140 cycles on Skylake (it took much less time on older CPUs): https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_pause&expand=5146

If the amount of time you want to sleep is small but you care about how much actual time has passed, you can check the time in a loop and call `_mm_pause()` once per loop.  About 70 ns for `clock_gettime()` plus 40 ns for `_mm_pause()` should give you a resolution somewhere around 120 ns on Skylake.

In either case, you will not be explicitly releasing the CPU core to be used by other processes, and the OS may unschedule your thread if there are other threads waiting to run on the same core.  So you'll need to set your CPU affinity such that nothing else can run on the same core.  For details see https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017747

See also: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops.html

Comment: Do not use `_mm_pause()` - that's only useful for preventing unwanted speculative execution in tight polling loops (so loop can exit faster when the data being polled changes, and so other logical processor in the core can run faster) and has nothing to do with time and is not a time delay.

Comment: What should I use then that doesn't take ages(relative) to pause in your opinion? I am trying out `umwait` at the moment but if you have a better way please do leave an answer @Brendan .

Comment: I can't seem to find much on how to use umwait so I am still open for answers.

Comment: @matapple: umwait is a fine suggestion apart from the fact that it is so new most computers don't support it.  Try `_mm_pause()` in a loop with checking the current time as I suggested and see if it does what you need.  If you can tell us your tolerances that would also help (i.e. do you need 1 microsecond precision or what).

Comment: Micro seconds good enough but nanosecond would be nice.

Comment: It works and I got the micro second resolution I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to pay for the thread context switch consider not switching thread context for example by using [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines).[Here Gor Nishanov claims that suspending and resuming a coroutine takes less than a nanosecond](https://youtu.be/j9tlJAqMV7U?t=298)

Comment: The operating system spawns a thread and this thread has a context for example the values in the CPU registers. If you have more threads than CPUs the operating system gives every thread some cpu time. If a thread gets suspended and later resumed the operating system needs to restore the context of this thread. [wiki context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)